# How to remove **A** sign in price of australia currency in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to remove **A** sign before dollar sign.I setup Australian Dollar currency in Magento2

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole site?

Comment: Yes I remove A sign from whole website

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to Stores => Currency Symbols (under Currency)
Step 2: Uncheck the Use Standard box under AUD currency symbol Input, by default, Magento 2 uses standard currency symbols.
Step 3:Remove A and Save currency Symbols

Comment: Thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

To enable Template Path Hints, go to Magento 2 Admin Panel -> STORES -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Debug -> Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront and change it to Yes. Once you are done, hit the Save Config button and now you should be able to see the changes on the frontend.

Find the phtml file by the path, you can change it there